# Sharepoint Hosted App - Get list Item using SPService call gives access denied why

Tags: spservices, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created a SharePoint hosted App for Office 365 and am trying to get list items using SPService call but it is not working.

There is an `Access denied` of `Forbidden 404` error, why?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have given necessary permission in `AppManifest.xml` file. You need to give `"Read"` access to `List/Web` for reading items from host web.

[image]

Comment: I have given Full Control in AppManifest.xml file to web  but still Access denied problem comes. So what I have to do ?

Comment: I just noticed you are using SPServices (my bad, sorry). I am not sure if SPServices has a provision to make cross domain calls. Can you try using JSOM or REST and check if that way works? I am assuming list is in host web. Find code snippet here http://www.mavention.com/blog/sharePoint-app-reading-data-from-host-web